# Rails refactor if block with redirections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have built pretty ugly `assert_jwe_token` if statement which in the controller acts as a redirect depending on whether the params exist and because of the different states of payload. Is there a way to improve the readability of below code:

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :assert_jwe_token

    private

    def assert_jwe_token
      if params[:jwe_token].blank?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
      elsif payload.failure?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: t('devise.registrations.jwe_register.failed')
      elsif payload_expired?(payload.value!)
        redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: t('devise.registrations.jwe_register.expired')
      end
    end

    def payload_expired?(payload)
      Time.now.utc.to_i < payload['exp']
    end

    def payload
      @payload ||= JweToken::DecryptJson.new(params[:jwe_token]).call
    end
  end
end
```

I was trying to extract some part of code to the helpers but it turns out the redirection won't work.

Comment: I don't think the readibility really is that bad. Whats worse is that it looks like you're adding a separate authentication system on top of Devise/Warden (and doing it wrong) which is a maintainence problem. If you want to add JWT token authentication to Devise the way to do it is by creating a Warden strategy. https://medium.com/@goncalvesjoao/rails-devise-jwt-and-the-forgotten-warden-67cfcf8a0b73

Comment: If you really want to reinvent the authentication wheel you should either raise an exception or do what Warden does and use `throw` so that the normal execution of the action and any callbacks is halted. Just using a callback and redirecting won't do that.

Comment: @max but it's JWE token not JWT. I'm using it to create user with this flow: 1. user gets the url generated by different app with JWE token as params (`users/sign_up/?jwe_token=some_gigantic_string_123`);
2. enter that url; 
3. under the hood Rails app creates new user based on encrypted params
after successful user creation redirect that user to the edit page;
Not quite sure where is an issue with my implementation.

Comment: You say Tomato I say Potato. It makes very little difference to the architecture. Warden already provides the tools to use any kind of authentication strategy.

Comment: Also JWE is just a form of JWT.

Comment: Yes but JWE is encrypted differently from what I now. Using JWT only to use jwt-devise flow with lots of exclusions (e.g. when it comes to holding the token, changing the token on the side of the service generating the link etc.) and JWE for decryption at the end anyway, doesn't seem like a consistent solution.